# Scatter plots from averaging a columns values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm working with 2 columns from a csv file: Month_num and Freight_In_(tonnes)

I'm attempting to plot the average value of freight for each month from 1987 to 2016. I can currently show each months average freight in, in table format but I'm struggling to get it to show in the scatter plot.

Here is my current code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CityPairs.csv')

Month = df.groupby(['Month_num'])['Freight_In_(tonnes)']
Month.mean()

plt.scatter(df['Month_num'], df['Freight_In_(tonnes)'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please give a sample of dataset you're using.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HGSyFFz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`df.groupby(['Month_num']).mean().reset_index().plot(kind='scatter',x='Month_num',y='Freight_In_(tonnes)')`

Comment: YES! thank you that worked a treat! How would you edit your code to do freight by country?

Comment: @Liam Please stick to one question per thread. If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it accepted. The next question you open, please include some of your data as text.

Comment: Yep my bad will do that in the future, I figured it out anyways!